# Can I force recaptcha expiration message to appear?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I'm trying to manipulate the recaptcha expiration message, but sometimes the message doesnt appear, i'dont know why, it is possible to force the expiration of recaptcha? Or set a lower timeout to the message.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't appear? How do you know if it expired if it doesn't appear? I have used recaptcha before, never had this issue

Comment: @Huangism, sometimes it appear, sometimes not, i want to force to expire the session

Comment: the js api allows you reset the widget which expires it but I am not sure if you are going to get any messages for it. But if you force expire it, then you can just show your own message to notify the user that it expired https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Comment: @Huangism, uhm, im trying to do it to change the expired message position, with css, when i use .reset() of recaptcha it doesnt show the message :(

Comment: Google does not allow you to do what you want, using reset you will need to display your own message